# C # Remover saltos de lineas de un texto y dejar todo en lineas

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo de texto linea por linea para luego almacenarlo en un DB.
La lectura del texto en si no es difícil lo que me esta complicando es que tengo saltos de lineas y no he podido sacarlos y dejar todo como las dos primeras lineas.(Ver Imagen)

[image: Consola Texto]

Este seria mi código hasta le momento.

```
            //Obtener base64 y convertir a Texto
            var archvivo = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            string carpeta = @"c:\LogTB";
            byte[] fileData = archvivo;
            File.WriteAllBytes(carpeta + "\\LogRecibido.txt", fileData);


            //Lectura del archvo
            var data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\LogTB\LogRecibido.txt").Replace("\r", "");


            var arreglo = new List<string[]>();

            // Convierte a lineas el contenido
            var lineas = data.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var linea in lineas)
            {
                var lineaArreglo = new List<string[]>();

                Console.WriteLine(linea);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
```

En que estaría fallando mi código??
Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Lo que quieres es que al hacer `Console.WriteLine()` aparezca todo en la misma línea?

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es la información que quieres en una línea.

Comment: Estoy tratando que quede todo como las primeras lineas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que buscas usando [`string.Join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) de la siguiente manera:

```
string linea = string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\LogTB\LogRecibido.txt"));
```

De esta manera lees todas las líneas del archivo y las separas por `" "`, con lo cual, te quedarían en una sola línea, que es lo que comentas que estás buscando.

---

**Solución después del comentario aclaratorio de lo que se busca.**

Sabiendo que lo que quieres es obtener la línea que te está dividiendo en una sola línea, lo que deberías hacer es comprobar que la línea que estas leyendo termine con el caracter `]`, y si no lo hace, concatenar el texto de la línea a las siguientes hasta que una de ellas termine con `]`.

Lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
string str = "";
foreach (var linea in lineas)
{
    str += linea;
    if (str.Trim().EndsWith(']'))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        str = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Si te fijas en la imagen la 2 primeras lineas son como debe quedar el texto.
La 3ra linea al final se corta por el salto de linea que viene desde un archivo que genera el sistema. 
Lo que busco es que la ultima parte de las lineas quede igual como las 2 primeras lineas.

Comment: @FelipeMorales He editado mi respuesta, echale un vistazo a ver si te sirve esto

Comment: Gracias @Marc, funciono perfecto!!!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya está cerrada creo que tener una segunda solución mediante expresiones regulares puede estar bien. Así que compoarto la expresión regular que lo solucionaría:

```
string textoModificado = Regex.Replace(texto, @"\[{1}[^\]]*(\r\n)+[^\]]*\]", (m) =>
{
    return m.Groups[0].Value.Replace("\r\n", " ");
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

var data = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\LogTB\LogRecibido.txt").Replace("\n", " ");

> Notas

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66xZj.png]